# inserting data (.jpg) files into a sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, flutter

Is there anyway to insert files into a sqlite database file without calling from a server.  My app has a standalone sqlite file(no connection to server) and want to  insert files into it to then query and show on my flutter app.

I used readfile to store the file and writefile to call on it.

```
insert into test (file,name) values (readfile('logo.jpg'), 'image');

select writefile ('logo.jpg', file) from test where name='image';
```

this returns bytes in my terminal, but when i query the "select writefile" in the app it will not return the document because it doesn't recognize the function writefile.

Am i on the right path for what i want to achieve?

Comment: The fileio stuff is available as a dynamic module you can compile and load, but I think most people would just select the blob and do their own file writing because it's so trivial. The [incremental blob API](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_open.html) might also be useful for extracting the data if whatever SQLite binding you're using supports it..

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a limited number of files(images), then you consider using the app's local file system.

You can find examples [here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/)

Answer (score -1):

SQLite is not capable of handling pictures or anything like that in its databases, the only supported data types are TEXT, INTEGER, REAL and BLOB. You could store the path of the image inside of your database though...

Comment: What do you think `BLOB` types are meant for?

Comment: Sure you could store a whole image within the database, but I think storing the image in a different folder and only storing the path to it would speed up loading times.

Comment: Depends. https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html is a good starting point.

Comment: What i am trying to do is break up a pdf file and break it down in smaller pieces so i can query specific information from it.  I would have a hundred files to search on. Are you saying that this would be very inefficient and not possible with sqlite?